# CoreDataTableViewController shows blank view

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'm building an app that has a view with a series of table cells at the top, and then a tableview which is populated from a CoreData SQLite database.

I have set the interface to be:

```
@interface ProjectDetailController : CoreDataTableViewController  <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
```

However, when I run the app in the simulator or on a device, the view is blank. The only thing that is displayed is the background.

When I change the interface back to `@interface ProjectDetailController : UITableViewController  <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>`—inheriting from `UITableViewController` instead—the view works, but I can't get data from the database, as the controller is not a `CoreDataTableViewController`.

Any help would be great.

Comment: What do you mean "the view works" when you change back to UITableViewController? I'm sure most people here don't know what CoreDataTableViewController is. Can you provide more info?

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing the Stanford Class?  The class you list is not provided by Cocoa.  It was a custom class provided for the Stanford class.  Do you have the interface/implementation file for this as provided by Stanford?

If not, then you need to read up on the basics of Core Data as far as Managed Object Contexts and FetchedResultsControllers.